# PHP unable to correct problems, you have held proken packages

Tags: php

I am currently trying to install a php version above 7.1.3 on my Raspberry pi 3b+ (runnning raspbian 9 and the current php version is 7.0.033). My apache is version 2.4 (the newest if i am not wrong). I need a php the php version above 7.1.3 to run my phpmyadmin server (version 5.1.0).

I have tried numerous things people suggested but i keep getting the same error where dependencies are not installed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQZka.jpg

I also manualy tried to install the dependencies, but dependencies have dependencies and i can't get them to download and install. Anyone who has idea's ? i tried a lot of things, this is my last hope

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to help you, if you don't state, what you already tried. I.e. did you try the [offical guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md) on how to install PHP on apache-servers?

---

"To allow your Apache server to process PHP files, you'll need to install the latest version of PHP and the PHP module for Apache"

Try installing the newest Version of PHP with

```
sudo apt install php -y
```

As well as the newest apache2-mod-php

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php -y
```